# to create a gallery in asp.net by iterating through the folders

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to create a gallery in asp.net the way it should work is as follows:

- iterate through gallery folder
- select all the folder and show them as albums with cover pic as thumbnail.jpg in that folder
- when clicked on the album it should display the content of the folder (images).

My approach for creating this was to iterate through the folders and make views and link button based on that for albums and to display the content of album in that view as images using repeater control, but that didn't work out as it had many errors while implementing it. and I had to write the whole thing in on_init() function because of dynamic views.I can implement the html and js part (like for light box and other  visual stuffs). 
Please suggest some better approach maybe with some code example. Please use c# . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not just write you all the code... but ill give you a startup code:

```
int scanLVL = 4;//or however deep you need to go...
public  void GetImageFromDir(string sourceDir, int startLVL)
{
    if (startLVL <= scanLVL)
    {
        // Here you can process files found in the directory.
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
        Label_showdata.Text +="<br />Dir:" +  Path.GetFileName(sourceDir) ;
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            // do something with fileName
            String tree = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < startLVL; i++)
                tree += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            Label_showdata.Text += "<br />" + tree + Path.GetFileName(fileName);               
        }

        // Going in subdirectories of this directory.
        string[] subdirEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir);
        foreach (string subdir in subdirEntries)

            if ((File.GetAttributes(subdir) &  FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) !=    FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)

                GetImageFromDir(subdir, startLVL + 1);
    }
}
```

This will print you on your web page(actualy in that Label_showdata) all the files and the directory where they are.
Basically from here you will need to wrap that data into a table and bind it in whatever control you feel comfortable with... Is not that hard actually... but it takes a bit more time to write exactly all the code (time that unfortunatlly i do not have at the moment...)

Comment: Hey your solution is good and the same way I have done it previously but the problem was with implementing it with views and repeater control. By the way I just have 1 level of folder.